# using cloudflare to get ssl on a custom domain hosted on github

Tags: https, dns

I was pointing a custom domain to my username.github.io account, by using A records in Domain Registrar (Route 53) and a CNAME in my master branch that said custom_domain.me. I want to move to https.

I created an account on cloudflare, changes the NS records on Route 53 to point to cloudflare, and changed CNAME record in my master branch to https://custom_domain.me.

I want to access https://custom_domain.me, but I cannot. I have waiting only one hour now. Am I missing something or should I just wait?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use CloudFlare on a Free/Pro account; you will need to move your DNS to CloudFlare, not just simply add NS records to Route53.

Route53 commonly provide simply DNS services, you have an interesting use-case as your also using their domain name registration service.

If your domain is registered with Route53 and also using Route53 for DNS, you will need to change this so CloudFlare does your DNS by changing the nameservers.

Once with CloudFlare, your DNS will be entirely managed by CloudFlare. Run through the CloudFlare set-up, verify your DNS records and you'll be presented with 2 new CloudFlare nameservers to use.

In order to configure this, please set the nameservers in Route53 to the ones in CloudFlare: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html